# Cordova google maps camera not moving

Tags: cordova, camera

We have a camera handler that should try to keep the camera focused on a specific area. If you scroll too far, it should return the camera to the central point and if you zoom out too far it should zoom in again.

We register this handler on `plugin.google.maps.event.CAMERA_CHANGE`. The handler is correctly triggered and will follow the correct codepath. It will set the position of the camera (we have tried moveCamera, animateCamera and simply setCenter/setZoom). If we then check the position of the camera using the `getCameraPosition`, we see that the camera reports back the correct (new) position.

So everything works as it should except that visually **nothing changes**. From a user perspective, the camera stays put, even though it is reporting its new position in the console correctly.

```
    var cameraHandler = function (position) {
        // Create an outer LatLngBounds object that borders our map
        var outerBounds = new application.services.maps.LatLngBounds([
            new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(
                application.configuration.location.bottomLeft.latitude,
                application.configuration.location.bottomLeft.longitude
            ),
            new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(
                application.configuration.location.topRight.latitude,
                application.configuration.location.topRight.longitude
            )
        ]);
        // Center of the map
        var mapCenter = new application.services.maps.LatLng(
            application.configuration.location.center.latitude,
            application.configuration.location.center.longitude
        );
        var self = this;
        // Current center
        var center = new application.services.maps.LatLng(position.target.lat, position.target.lng);
        // Zoom levels
        var zoom = {
            min: 11,
            max: 17,
            default: 15
        };
        // Check if map is in bounds
        if (!outerBounds.contains(center)) {
            this.animateCamera({
                target: mapCenter,
                duration: 1200
            }, function() {
                self.getCameraPosition(function(camera) {
                    console.log("AFTER MOVE CAMERA POSITION", camera);
                });
            });
        }
        if (Math.ceil(position.zoom) <= zoom.min) {
            this.animateCamera({
                "zoom": zoom.default,
                "duration": 600
            }, function() {
                self.getCameraPosition(function(camera) {
                    console.log("AFTER ZOOM CAMERA POSITION", camera);
                });
            });
        }
    };
```